# Dockerized Angular frontend cant access dockerized python backend

Tags: angular, docker, rest, http, networking

I have two docker container running on my aws instance.
The frontend is working as intented. Now I added a python backend.
I created a docker network for that:

```
sudo docker network create foo
```

I added both container to this network by:

```
sudo docker network connect foo containername1
sudo docker network connect foo containername2
```

If i go into my frontend container with:

```
docker exec containerid /bin/bash
```

and do a curl:

```
curl containerName:8020/endpoint
```

I get the expected result! That means from within my frontend docker container I can access the python backend.

The problem now is, I created a angular production build and uploaded it on my aws instance as a apache docker and I cant access the backend data from the browser. This is the browser error message in the console:

```
message: "Http failure response for http://xxx.xxx.../endpoint: 0 Unknown Error"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 0
statusText: "Unknown Error"
url: "http://xxx.xxx.../endpoint"
```

I anonymised the ip, so that is not the real one!
I tried it with using the ip adress from the docker network (when docker inspect) and with the containername:8020/endpoint. The curl from within the frontend docker container both got me the expected results.

My question now is: How do I access the docker backend to retrieve the data in my application?

EDIT:
Python dockerfile

```
# set base image (host OS)
FROM python:3.8

# set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR .

# copy the dependencies file to the working directory
COPY requirements.txt .

# install dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# copy the content of the local src directory to the working directory
COPY . .

# command to run on container start
CMD [ "python", "./api.py" ]
```

Comment: can you provide the docker images you started from?

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been more specific. Can you share the angular Dockerfile?

Comment: I just use a standard apache docker and upload the build dist into it.

Comment: ok, I realize the title is misleading, sorry about that.

Comment: ok, are you using a proxy reverse from the apache to the python when a specific request is used?

Comment: I do not. Thanks, I need to read into it!

Comment: consider using nginx for this, IMHO it's a little less stressful to deal with